# How to loop data and print each iteration to PDF in a defined Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a novice at GAS, so please bear with me.

I'd like to create a script for a Google Sheet that will loop through a series of values, pause at each value, and print a specific tab from the sheet to a defined location in Google Drive (creating a new folder with a date within the parent folder). Below is what I have so far, which achieves looping and printing, but I can't figure out how to get it to save the PDF files to a specific folder. Grateful for any help! Thank you.

Link to dummy spreadsheet with script [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F6fgrQpZH0BzwWSbcEpzFLThKbgifzZGYIUHTEYJ4ho/edit#gid=1207870189), and target Google Drive folder [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1QmjXLyssyCGU16ApLQ4Anj_kir0uuQS8).

```
function loop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var validation_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var lastRow = validation_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = ss.getSheetByName('Validation').getRange('A2:A'+lastRow).getValues();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");

  //Create Folder for PDFs
  var fld = DriveApp.createFolder(formattedDate);
  fld.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()));

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sheet2.getRange('A1').setValue(inputs[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

  //Print PDFs
  var name = tab.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  fld.createFile(ss.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(name);
  }
  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to create PDF files to "target Google Drive folder". `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1QmjXLyssyCGU16ApLQ4Anj_kir0uuQS8`

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Retrieve the target folder using `DriveApp.getFolderById()`.
- When PDF file is created, it creates the file to the target folder.

#### Modified script:

```
function loop() {
  var targetFolderId = "1QmjXLyssyCGU16ApLQ4Anj_kir0uuQS8"; // Added
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId); // Added

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var validation_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var lastRow = validation_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = ss.getSheetByName('Validation').getRange('A2:A'+lastRow).getValues();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
//  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"); // Removed

  //Create Folder for PDFs
//  var fld = DriveApp.createFolder(formattedDate); // Removed
//  fld.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId())); // Removed

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sheet2.getRange('A1').setValue(inputs[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

  //Print PDFs
  var name = tab.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  targetFolder.createFile(ss.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(name); // Modified
  }
//  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId())); // Removed
}
```

#### Note:

- In your script, the active spreadsheet is also moved to a created new folder. About this, how do you want to do?

#### References:

- [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit:

- When you run the script, at first, you want to create new folder in the target folder. Then, you want to create PDF files in the created folder.
- About the active spreadsheet, do nothing.

I understood like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function loop() {
  var targetFolderId = "1QmjXLyssyCGU16ApLQ4Anj_kir0uuQS8"; // Added
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId); // Added

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var validation_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Validation');
  var lastRow = validation_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = ss.getSheetByName('Validation').getRange('A2:A'+lastRow).getValues();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName('Loadout');
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+5", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");

  //Create Folder for PDFs
  var fld = targetFolder.createFolder(formattedDate); // Modified
//  fld.addFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId())); // Removed

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sheet2.getRange('A1').setValue(inputs[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);

    //Print PDFs
    var name = tab.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
    fld.createFile(ss.getAs('application/pdf')).setName(name); // Modified
  }
//  DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId())); // Removed
}
```

Comment: This is a great improvement @Tanaike thank you. I should clarify that the goal is to create a new folder (with the current date) within the Target Folder, and that's where the PDFs should be stored. Regarding the movement of the active spreadsheet, it seems that in your script, it actually stays in its original location, which is where it should stay (it should not move to a different folder). Looking forward to your response, thank you.

Comment: @pminc Thank you for replying. I'm really sorry I misunderstand what you want. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike this modified script works perfectly!

Comment: @pminc I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.